# Python typing the return type of a curried function automatically

Tags: python, python-typing

Consider the following correctly annotated python code:

```py
def make_repeater(times: int) -> Callable[[str, str], str]:
    def repeat(s: str, s2: str) -> str:
        return (s + s2) * times
    return repeat
```

Is there a way to simplify the return type so that you do not need to specify the type twice?

A generic approach will work, but the information about the function annotation will disappear when you call the function.

```py
def make_repeater(times: int) -> Callable
    def repeat(s: str, s2: str) -> str:
        return (s + s2) * times
    return repeat
```

You can also specify nothing and mypy will correctly guess the type. Is there something better than

```py
def make_repeater(times: int) # type: ignore[no-untyped-def]:
    def repeat(s: str, s2: str) -> str:
        return (s + s2) * times
    return repeat
```

Edit: fixed the type annotations returning a int rather than str

Comment: btw `Callable` on its own is not generic. It becomes `Callable[..., Any]` which means arguments and return type are untyped rather than generic. Generic might be `Callable[[T, T], U]`

Comment: to be pedantic, this isn't function currying.

Answer (score 2):

You gave yourself some options. To improve beyond these would depend on your application, but here's one way to at least save a couple lines (with [lambdas](https://realpython.com/python-lambda/#arguments)):

```
def make_repeater(times: int) -> Callable[[str, str], str]:
    return lambda s1, s2: (s1 + s2) * times
```

If your goal is to produce Callables that have their own type hints without writing out the type hints twice, you could also just avoid the nesting; for example, by implementing `repeat()` as a class method where `times` is an accessible attribute.

Also your type hints for `repeat()` are incorrect here (it will return `str`, not `int`).

Comment: this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: indeed, they already answered their own question; I'm not aware of any methods to "simplify the return type so that you do not need to specify the type twice" outside of relying on mypy. However, as suggested above, they can restructure their function generator as an object if their application depends on type hinting at both levels; or if they simply want to make things visually cleaner or satisfy a linter or something, use a lambda.